# What exactly is the 'platforms' argument for gem in Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

To start with basics, I see things like this in the Gemfile

```rb
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Is this code telling the Gemfile: "only install tzinfo-data gem if the platform is one of these: mingw, mswin, x64_mingw, jruby; if it's any other operating system, don't install it"?

Background: The reason for the interest in this is because I get a warning when running `bundle install` and I just want to understand how it all works before I start tinkering with it.

Also note: I searched https://api.rubyonrails.org/ for 'gem', 'group', and 'platforms' but I couldn't spot an explanation there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also note: I searched https://api.rubyonrails.org/ for 'gem', 'group', and 'platforms' but I couldn't spot an explanation there.

Makes sense, Gemfiles aren't part of Rails. They are provided by [Bundler](https://bundler.io/).

> Is this code telling the Gemfile: "only install tzinfo-data gem if the platform is one of these: mingw, mswin, x64_mingw, jruby; if it's any other operating system, don't install it"?

Yes, exactly. You can read about their exact meanings in the [Platform section of the Gemfile docs](https://bundler.io/v2.3/man/gemfile.5.html#PLATFORMS).

In particular, the [`tzinfo` gem](https://tzinfo.github.io/) needs an up-to-date [time zone databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). It will use the one installed on the operating system. If the operating system doesn't provide one, or if it doesn't keep it up to date, you can install the [`tzinfo-data` gem](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo-data). Most non-Windows machines maintain their own time zone database.

Comment: Thanks not only for explaining, but for the links; gives me some places to start further reading. Is bundler.io the best place to go for bundler documentation? When I search for some of the ruby (as opposed to command line) commands that bundler provides (e.g 'gem', 'group') I can't spot them. Should I simply assume the ruby code in Gemfile is doing them equivalent of the bundle (bash) command? For example `gem 'rails'` in Gemfile is equivalent to `gem install rails` in bash?

Comment: @stevec Gemfiles and `gem` are intimately related, but they are separate projects. Bundler is Gemfiles and `bundle`. Bundler is for managing gems, but `gem` is not part of Bundler. `gem` is part of [RubyGems](https://guides.rubygems.org/).

Comment: @stevec `gem 'rails'` in a Gemfile and `gem install rails` are similar in that they both install the Gem called `rails`. But `gem install rails` will install the latest version of `rails` for your user. `gem 'rails'` will install only for that project, and the newest version which is compatible with all the other installed gems in the project, and will record which version was installed in `Gemfile.lock`. This way when anyone runs `bundle` they get the same versions of the same gems as everyone else. It avoids "dependency hell" as new releases of gems happen.